# Ubuntu 14.04 detects Vodafone 3g dongle, but fails to connect

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, usb-modem, 3g

Earlier I used Ubuntu 12.04 where my Vodafone 3G Dongle (HUWAEI modem) used to connect seamlessly via network manager Mobile Broadband. Now I have upgraded my system and using Ubuntu 14.04, but whenever I try to connect to Vodafone 3G using the network manager, it searches for some time and fails to connect.

When I plug in the device, Ubuntu network manager detects it and displays the name, on clicking it first it searches to connect and displays the following message "Mobile Broadband Network : You are registered to home network", which is expected. But then, it fails to connect and disconnects the connection.

Now installation of the software given in the modem is a nightmare as everytime it fails for some reason, thats why in my 12.04 I used to connect via the Network Manager. I have checked the APN settings which is standard for Vodafone.

Device : Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E398 LTE/UMTS/GSM Modem/Networkcard
Vodafone 3g K4203I

Thanks!

[image: Problem]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like there is some problem with the driver of your modem. I have tried a script called Sakis3G to get some unsupported dongles working in Ubuntu. This should work just fine for your dongle too. Download it from here: http://dev.oikyolinux.com/files/sakis3g.7z Please see the read me file included in the 7z archive if having problem executing the script.

Comment: yes this script worked perfectly! Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: What did you use for apn username and password ?

Comment: Those fields should be blank for most cases.